# TCP connections with overlapped I/O

Tags: winapi, tcp, winsock, overlapped-io, request-cancelling

Is it possible to initiate a TCP connection request with overlapped I/O, and cancel it before the connection has been completed in Windows? I need to support at least Windows XP SP2.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`ConnectEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms737606%28VS.85%29.aspx) allows an overlapped connection attempt.

To cancel this one would need to use [`CancelIo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363791%28VS.85%29.aspx) passing the `SOCKET` as if it were a `HANDLE` (it is really). But this *must* be done from the same thread that called `ConnectEx`. Managing things so you can achieve that thread specificity is unlikely to be easy.

After XP/2003 (ie. Vista/2008/8/2008R2) you can use [`CancelIoEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363792%28VS.85%29.aspx) from a different thread (the `OVERLAPPED` instance is used to fully identify the IO operation).

Comment: You could probably also cancel that connect attempt simply by closing the socket; the ConnectEx() will then fail...

Comment: @Richard: Awesome, thanks! I will be cancelling from the same thread that issued the call to ConnectEx(), so this won't be a problem. But, does anybody know what happens on TCP-level? Suppose SYN has been sent, will cancelling the connect send an RST to the other side, or will it keep the handshake hanging?

Answer (score 1):

From [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738545%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> overlap
>
> This directory contains a sample server program that uses overlapped
>   I/O. The sample program uses the AcceptEx function and overlapped I/O
>   to handle multiple asynchronous connection requests from clients
>   effectively. The server uses the AcceptEx function to multiplex
>   different client connections in a single-threaded Win32 application.
>   Using overlapped I/O allows for greater scalability.